# (bluetooth low energy) Subscribe to a characteristic when peripheral sends a "indication". Using Noble

Tags: node.js, bluetooth-lowenergy, health-monitoring

I'm trying to read from my Blood Pressure using noble(https://github.com/abandonware/noble) BLE.
The service is 1810 and the characteristic is 2a35, but the buffer is empty. The properties is: [ 'indicate' ]

I know that i have to subscribe to read the buffer, but i don't know how to do this. Someone cann help?
I using this code:

```js
const noble = require('@abandonware/noble');


noble.on('stateChange', async (state) => {
    if (state === 'poweredOn') {
        console.log('Scanning');
        await noble.startScanningAsync([], false);
    } else {
        noble.stopScanning();
    }
});

noble.on('discover', peripheral => {
    // connect to the first peripheral that is scanned
    noble.stopScanning();
    const name = peripheral.advertisement.localName;
    console.log(`Connecting to '${name}' ${peripheral.id}`);
    connectAndSetUp(peripheral);
});

function connectAndSetUp(peripheral) {
    peripheral.connect(error => {
        console.log('Connected to', peripheral.id);

        // specify the services and characteristics to discover
        const serviceUUIDs = ['1810'];
        const characteristicUUIDs = ['2a35'];

        peripheral.discoverSomeServicesAndCharacteristics(
            serviceUUIDs,
            characteristicUUIDs,
            onServicesAndCharacteristicsDiscovered
        );
    });

    peripheral.on('disconnect', () => console.log('disconnected'));
}

function onServicesAndCharacteristicsDiscovered(error, services, characteristics) {
    console.log('Discovered services and characteristics');
    const echoCharacteristic = characteristics[0];
    console.log(echoCharacteristic);

    // console.log( echoCharacteristic.read());
   
    // data callback receives notifications
    echoCharacteristic.on('data', (data, isNotification) => {
        console.log(`Received: "${data}"`);
    });

    // echoCharacteristic.once('data',data => console.log("oii "+data));
    // subscribe to be notified whenever the peripheral update the characteristic
     echoCharacteristic.subscribe( (error) => {
        if (error) {
            console.error('Error subscribing to echoCharacteristic');
        } else {
            // console.log( echoCharacteristic.Buffer);
            console.log('Subscribed for echoCharacteristic notifications');
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: i want to read a buffer that contains some data, but isn't workig. I suppose that echoCharacteristic.subscribe( (error) is the problem. Have you already use noble?

Comment: You should add an error message or a log out put to show whats not working if asking on StackOverflow the next time. Also tell us the version of noble you are using. Have a look at this full central example from noble https://github.com/noble/noble/blob/master/examples/pizza/central.js